# Wrapping multiple children with same class name in multiple divs jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to us the jquery Method wrapAll to wrap multiple children with the same class name in multiple parents with the same class name, once the window size is less the 706.

I want to go from this.

```
<div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

To this.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Heres my jQuery

```
  if ($(window).width() < 705) {
   $( ".a,.b" ).wrapAll( "<div class='a-b'></div>" );
  }
  else {

  }
```

Do I need to give them all individual class names and create 3 different wrapAll methods? Or is there a way I can do it all with one method/function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isolate the parent instances and look inside each one for the groups to wrap

```js
$('.list').each(function(){
 $(this).find( ".a,.b" ).wrapAll( "<div class='a-b'></div>" );
})
```

```css
.a-b{border:1px solid green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="a">A item</div>
  <div class="b">B item</div>
  <div class="c">C Item</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="a">A item</div>
  <div class="b">B item</div>
  <div class="c">C Item</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="a">A item</div>
  <div class="b">B item</div>
  <div class="c">C Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like it will work, I can't get it too though idk if it's the window().width or the wrap I'm not getting any console errors.

Comment: did you wrap code in document.ready? Or call it after elemetns exist?

Comment: I got it I hadn't changed the parent class name to the one I'm using. Thank you!

Comment: I got it working how ever its wrapping the children in 2 "a-b" divs instead of just one

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle that reproduces problem

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you could loop over all the `.a` elements, get their sibling `.b`, then use `wrapAll()` to contain them within another `div`, like this:

```js
$('.a').each(function() {
  var $b = $(this).next('.b');
  $(this).add($b).wrapAll('<div />');
});
```

```css
/* this is just to make the div structure more obvious in the output */
div { 
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```